# How can I not apply something to the :first item?

Tags: jquery

So this is probably super simple but I am trying to not applyong the makeshort function to the first div on my page.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? If it's not elegant let me know-I'm a newbie :)

```
function makeShort(){ 
  if  (jQuery(this).not(':first')) {
    jQuery(this).css('z-index','1').find('.bottom-bg .excerpt').animate({"height":75},200);
    jQuery('.entry').removeClass('active').animate({opacity:1},200);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is makeShort being called from?

Comment: where does "this" come from? and you're css line should start with jQuery rather than Query;)

Comment: It's being called from: jQuery(".entry").hoverIntent({
   over: makeTall,
   timeout: 100,
   out: makeShort
  });

Answer (score 2):

`.mycollection` is your selector

```
$('.mycollection:gt(0)')
```

**EDIT**

```
$(this).filter(':gt(0)')
```

this will give you all the items in the collection whose index is greater than 0 (the first item). So if `$(this)` is a collection of 3 items, `$(this).filter(':gt(0)')` will give you all items after the first one, which in this contrived example would be the last 2.

**References:**

- [Working Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/5rP6f/)
- [:gt(index)](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)
- [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment you added, you are trying to filter in the wrong place.  Rather than filtering in the function itself, only apply `hoverIntent` to the elements you want it on.

```
$("div").not(":first").hoverIntent(...
```

and then makeShort is just:

```
function makeShort(){ 
    jQuery(this).css('z-index','1').find('.bottom-bg .excerpt').animate({"height":75},200);
    jQuery('.entry').removeClass('active').animate({opacity:1},200);
}
```

This will not apply `hoverIntent` to the first `div` so you don't need to worry about it in the function.

EDIT (based on comment below):

```
   function makeShort(){
      if(this!=jQuery("div:first")[0]){ 
        jQuery(this).css('z-index','1').find('.bottom-bg .excerpt').animate({"height":75},200);
        jQuery('.entry').removeClass('active').animate({opacity:1},200);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Kingjiv, but I actually wanted some of the other things within hoverIntent to happen to the first div-just not the makShort() function.

Comment: @Sean ah okay, check my edit, I think that will work.  May want to save `jQuery("div:first")[0]` to a variable so you don't have to select it each time.

Comment: wow thanks very much! Worked great. Why is the [0] necessary even though you're saying :first?

Comment: It is still a jquery object and not a dom object, you need to get the dom object out, even if there is only one.